# hadoop tasktracker: why logs are missed in userlogs?

Tags: hadoop, logging

I am using hadoop1.2.1. I need stdout file in /hadoop-installation-directory/logs/userlogs/job-*/attemp-*/stdout. but when i restarted datanodes, my job logs isn't in userlogs. is anyway to access them? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why log files gets purged:

- It's purged every 24 hours by default as defined by 'mapreduce.job.userlog.retain.hours' property (for Gen 2 for Gen 1 its mapred.userlog.retain.hours)
- Its purged every 12 hours as defined in default log4j.properties

  ```
  hadoop.tasklog.taskid=null
  hadoop.tasklog.noKeepSplits=4
  hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize=100
  hadoop.tasklog.purgeLogSplits=true
  hadoop.tasklog.logsRetainHours=12
                                 ^^
  ```

So if you have configuration like this, then it will just retain logs for 12 hours.